# Fastest way to get records in one set but not another

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have a query like this

```
with ds as (select ...)
select * 
from table
where id not in (select * from ds)
```

but the inner select statement and the outer one (from table) both are like 200k records, and this is taking too long to compute. Is there a more efficient way to find records in table, that are not from the nested select statement?

Comment: Use a `NOT EXISTS`? `NOT IN (SELECT *...`) won't work though; `IN` expects a set of *scalar* values to be returned.

Comment: You can use an OUTER JOIN or a NOT EXISTS. Those are generally more performant than an IN clause. Also make sure you have indexes on the columns you are joining/matching.

Comment: can you show an example of not exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: [Example E: Using NOT EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-not-exists)

Comment: You'll have to test it, because it depends. Please read right to the end (or at the very least read the conclusion paragraph): https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join Also, see [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Stop guessing. Look at the execution plan to understand what the engine is doing and evaluate what you can do to improve it.

Comment: For performance questions you need to tell us what indexes the tables have, and share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Igor That is a complete myth: `EXISTS` and `IN` [perform the same](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) (and usually better than `LEFT JOIN... IS NULL`) except that `NOT IN` can give incorrect results where nulls are involved.

Comment: Good link @Charlieface, thank you. I did a little more reading on the matter and it seems that whether a IN/NOT IN is performant can also depend on if the column is nullable or not. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/1260204. I retract what I said in my earlier comment about performance.

Comment: @Igor That is only true in the case of `NOT IN` not `IN`, and in any case the issue of incorrect results is more overriding than its performance. The reason it is slower is that it has to do more work to get those incorrect results: the semantics of `NOT IN` are the same as `a <> b1 AND a <> b2` which is subtly different if there are nulls, whereas `IN` becomes `a = b1 OR a = b2` which behaves the same whether or not there are nulls. You can see this in the query plans

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the first query in "view" or "function" and then use them for other usages.
example:

create view View1 ...
usage: select * from View1

create function Function1 (@value int) ...
usage: select * from Function1(20)

Comment: And how is this going to perform better?

Comment: In this link, you can see the differences between View and CTE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918633/sql-cte-vs-view